# Using Boxlayout is causing my Panel to only be half the size of the parent panel

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, boxlayout

I am using a JPanel as a Main panel to display information to my users.

I have created 3 other Jpanels using methods.  titlePanel, verbiagePanel, closeButtonPanel.  Each of these methods are assigned as a component  and added to the main panel.  I am using BoxLayout in the main panel as well as the other panels.

```
  Component titlePanel = titlePanel();
  Component verbiagePanel = verbiagePanel();
  Component closeButtonPanel = closeButton();

  this.setTitle("EDI - Help Page");
  //this.setResizable( false );

  centerPanel = new JPanel();
  centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
  centerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 300));
  centerPanel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  centerPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
  centerPanel.add(verbiagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  centerPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 2)));
  centerPanel.add(closeButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  getContentPane().add(centerPanel);
  this.pack();
```

Above it the main panel Method.  When I compile and run the dialog, everything looks right except the verbiagePanel.  It is only half the size of the parent panel and the other 2 panels.

[image]

Here is the code for my verbiagePanel

```
 private JPanel verbiagePanel() {
  String titleText = "<html><font size=4><b><center>How To Use This Application</b></center></font></html>";
  String text = "<html>" +
        "  <P align=left><font size=3>" +
        "   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1. Add a data to the list of Selected Datasets.<br/>" +
        "   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(see below for detailed instructions on adding datasets)<br/>" +
        "   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2. Select the project to send data to.<br/>" +
        "   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3. Adjust the list of selected 3D or 2D translators if desired.<br/>" +
        "   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4. Use the Send button to continue the EDI transaction." +
        "  </font></P>" +
        "  </html>";


  JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(titleText, JLabel.CENTER);
  titleLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

  JLabel bodyLabel = new JLabel(text, JLabel.LEFT);
  bodyLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

  JPanel p = new JPanel();
  p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
  p.add(titleLabel);
  p.add(bodyLabel);
  p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
  return p;   
}
```

The funny thing is, if I remove the BoxLayout from the Panel.  The Panel will expand to match the other 2 panels. But the spacing of the labels are crazy.  I will end up having at least 5 labels in the panel.  Right now I am only showing 2 to make it more simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using GrigBagLayout model.  It worked as needed.